# Magento 2 : load order by id in customer account order view

Tags: magento2, blocks, sales-order, phtml

In the customer account order view page, I added a Block and an associated phtml file. Inside this phtml, I would like to load the order to access some information.

NB: the block is added dynamically and not using XML

I tried in my block :

```
protected $_order;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
        )
{
    $this->_order = $order;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

and in my pthml :

```
 $order = $block->_order->load($data['order_id']);
```

but it results in an error.

If someone could give me a hand, please?

Answer (score 21):

Try following way:

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getOrder($id)
{
    return $this->orderRepository->get($id);
}
```

From phtml

```
$order = $block->getOrder($data['order_id']);
```

Comment: It show an error that id is undefined

Answer (score 11):

Declare `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` in construct of your class.

Try following snippet:

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
){
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}
```

Then you can do following:

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId(); // To get order incremental id
```